# Button inside Mapbox popup not executing function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I am trying to open a modal when a button inside of a Mapbox popup is clicked. The HTML is rendering properly but I'm not sure as to why the function is not being executed.

```
let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el);
    try {
        marker.setLngLat([eventInfo.location[0], eventInfo.location[1]])
            .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 32})
                .setHTML('<ion-button (click)="logger()">View Full</ion-button>'))
            .addTo(this.map);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
```

Above is how I create the marker and attach a popup. `logger()` is the function that I expect to be executed.

```
logger(){
  console.log('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Ionic works, but my guess is you can't just pass Ionic HTML elements (`<ion-button>`) to `setHTML` and expect it to get the full Ionic treatment. (That's the case with React and Vue for instance.)

One solution would be to write conventional raw HTML in the `setHTML`:

```js
.setHTML('<button id="view-full">View Full')
.addTo(this.map);

document.getElementById('view-full').addEventListener('click', logger)
```

Alternatively there might be some step to pass your HTML through Ionic to get it to behave as you expect.

Comment: Hi Steve, are you able to show how it would work for vue? Struggling to get it working for vue components while using quasar.
Would appreciate your help!